# i want to create Simple Vote Poll without clicking button,but it doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is vote.php whitch is located in uploads,when i require vote.php whole content dissapears...

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';
    $yesOrNo=$_POST['yesOrNo'];
if(isset($_POST['yesOrNo'])){
    header('location:index.php');
    if(!empty($yesOrNo)){
        $sqlv=$con->query("INSERT INTO votepoll (yesorno) VALUES ('{$yesOrNo}')");
    if($sqlv){


    }
    else{
        header('location:index.php');
    }
 }
}
?>
```

And This is form in user.php

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" value="yes"><span style="font-family:none;font-size:22px">YES</span>
<input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" value="no"><span style="font-family:none;font-size:22px">NO<br>
</form>
```

Comment: To put it short: you can't. What you're requesting would require AJAX.

Comment: I love this "just doesn't work". How often we see this "day in and day out". Check for errors, there are enough tools at your disposal. The failure here is obvious.

Comment: i don't want page to don't refresh or etc,i simply want if isset any of the votepoll,i mean Yes or No to just save it  in database,without clicking a button

Comment: @Fred-ii- man no errors i type else die(mysql_error()); nothing appears still and nothing works either

Comment: that's not what you need to use; you need error reporting; undefined index notice..............on line x

Comment: and `mysql_error()` does not work with mysqli_

Comment: ahh, fredi now i i'm just trying to do it in test.php,only notice appears:undefined index,but if i click Yes or No nothing happens simply,doesn't even save in database, if(isset($_POST['yesOrNo'])); does it work? i mean instead of button i check yesOrNo radio soo,idk man i can't understand what's happening

Comment: and agian i did a simple mistake,didn't wrote a method  <form method="POST">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form method missing,php code is okay.

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" value="yes"><span style="font-family:none;font-size:22px">YES</span>
<input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" value="no"><span style="font-family:none;font-size:22px">NO<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Damn it Was a really dumb mistake... Thanks for help m8!